# Wt (Witty) + Apache + Fastcgi

Tags: multithreading, apache, fastcgi, wt

I'm trying to understand how sessions are managed by Wt when using it through the fastcgi connector and apache, as a dynamic fastcgi script. My `wt_config.xml` is the default one. I changed nothing, so, the current Wt options about processes and threads management are the default ones:

```
<server>
  <application-settings location="*">
    <session-management>      
      <!--
        <dedicated-process>
          <max-num-sessions>100</max-num-sessions>
        </dedicated-process>
      -->

      <shared-process>
        <num-processes>1</num-processes>
      </shared-process>

      // Others....
    </session-management>

    <connector-fcgi>
      <num-threads>1</num-threads>
      // Others....
    </connector-fcgi>

    // Others...
  </application-settings>
</server>
```

- With such a configuration, how many process will I have? Just one for all the sessions? Or only one for **each** new session? What does `shared-process` exactly mean here?
- If I would use my app, for example, as a chat, using server pushes to refresh contents, wouldn't I get problems if I have more than one processes running at the same time? (because different clients could connect to different processes).

Answer (score 1):

When a Wt app works under Apache with FastCGI connector, first the Wt FastCGI dispatching process is launched. That process receives FastCGI requests from the web server and forwards them to worker processes which actually do your app job. Number of worker processes is controlled by `shared-process` option.  It's called shared because the number of active Wt sessions can eventually exceed the number of worker processes. In this case the dispatching process tries to distribute new Wt sessions evenly to working processes.

Unlike `shared-process` option, when you use `dedicated-process`, a new worker process will be launched for every new Wt session.

Push events sent by `WServer::post` or `WServer::postAll` will be delivered only to Wt sessions within the current process. If you want to post events to all Wt sessions in all process, you should implement some custom inter-process communication mechanism.

I've discussed it here: http://redmine.webtoolkit.eu/issues/2897